# Difference between char and char[x:y]

Tags: r

I would like to know what is the difference between *char* and  *char[x:y]*.

I have these two variables:

```
var1:chr"bla blabla blablabla..."
```

and

```
var2 : chr[1:3] "bla" "blabla" "blablabla"
```

Thank you in advance for clarifying me this ambiguity.

**EDIT**

I try to extract a vector of n-grams using ngramrr library with :

```
ngramrr(x, char = FALSE, ngmin = 1, ngmax = 2, rmEOL = TRUE)
```

where x is an input string

But when I try whith x where x is a `chr "bla blabla blablabla..."` it does not work,

Comment: Did you meant `chr` instead of `char`  If it is a vector, then `str(letters[1:5])#
 chr [1:5] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"` or if it is scalar i.e. `str(letters[1])#
 chr "a"`

Comment: Ok thank you, is there a way to convert `chr` to `chr[1:3]`?

Comment: You can do a `scan` i.e. `scan(text=yourvec, sep= " ", what = "", quiet=TRUE)`

Comment: What is your 'x'?

Comment: my "x" is `chr "hello world" "hello all the world" "good bye" " it is so awesome"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference between the two cases is based on the `length` of the `vector`.  If the `length` is one i.e a scalar element it will not show the range within `[]`.

```
str(letters[1])
#chr "a"

str(letters[1:5])
# chr [1:5] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

---

Based on the comments, it seems the OP have a character string with 3 words separted by space, if we want to separate the string, then use `strsplit` or `scan`

```
str1 <- "bla blabla blablabla"
str2 <- scan(text = str1, what ="", sep=" ", quiet = TRUE)
#or 
#str2 <- strsplit(str1, "\\s+")[[1]]

str(str2)
#chr [1:3] "bla" "blabla" "blablabla"
```

Comment: if `str1 <- "bla blabla blablabla" "bla blabla blalalala" "bababab"` how can i split into sentences?

Comment: @dr.nasri84  You can use `strsplit` i.e. `unlist(strsplit(str1, " "))` if i understand you

Comment: No it does not work... I think teher is another problem